# delete certificate inside the ivy downloaded jar

Tags: java, ant, certificate, netbeans-7, ivy

I am using jhall.jar in my project. I am using netbeans 7.1 for development. the build system, is ant and I am using apache ivy for dependency management. The problem is that the jhall.jar that ivy downloads from the maven repository is already signed and I want to unsign it. The way I am doing it right now is manually unzipping it and deleting the certificates inside META-INF folder in the jar file and making a jar again.

Now my question is that, is there any automated way of doing this ? does ant allow you to delete some file inside the jar ? Is there any way that I can exclude the download of just the certificates using ivy ?

Comment: Have a look at [Unsign a JAR with Ant - Gists - GitHub](https://gist.github.com/jarek-przygodzki/4981074).

Comment: Ivy is not designed to do this. It manages files as dependencies, not the contents of those files.

Comment: Once you've got an unsigned copy of the jhall jar, you could put it some place that your ivy resolver chain checks before maven central so you'll be sure to get that version in your Ivy dependency resolution.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor : Okay, thought so. I think ant might help me in this task.

Comment: @David : your suggestion will work but I want to use ivy for jhall, that way I can always get the latest.release version. Hence I was asking for the way in ant/ivy to do that

Comment: @Jost : Thanks for the link. It worked amazingly !